# Why does the border of QWidget cover the contents?

Tags: css, border, qwidget, qtstylesheets, qt5.9

I have a custom widget derived from `QWidget`, which has a `minimumSize` of `(30, 30)` and a `QLabel` as a `childWidget`:

```
MyWidget::MyWidget (QWidget *parent, QPoint p,
                  QWidget *childWidget) : QWidget (parent)
{
    childWidget = this->childWidget;
    setAttribute (Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    this->move (p);
    verticalLayout = new QVBoxLayout (this);

    if (childWidget != NULL)
    {
        childWidget->setParent (this);
        childWidget->releaseMouse();
        childWidget->setAttribute (Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents,     true);
        verticalLayout->addWidget (childWidget);
    }
    this->setLayout(verticalLayout);
};

MyWidget::mouseMoveEvent (QMouseEvent *e)
{
    if (! (e->button() == Qt::RightButton))
    {
        this->update();
        this->raise();
    }
}

void MyWidget::mouseReleaseEvent (QMouseEvent *evt)
{
    QWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(evt);
    this->update();
}

MyWidget::mousePressEvent (QMouseEvent *e)
{
    if (! (e->button() == Qt::RightButton))
    {

        this->update();
        this->raise();
    }
}

void MyWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    painter.setPen(Qt::darkGreen);
    painter.drawRect(1, 2, 6, 4);
    painter.setPen(Qt::darkGray);
    painter.drawLine(2, 8, 6, 2);
}

//And some getter/setter methods.
```

In order to set a border to the widget I use the following code:

```
 customWidget->setStyleSheet("*{border-width:" +
    2 +
    ";border-style:solid;border-color:" +
    #FFFFFF + " ;color:white;}");
```

It looks like this (the parent widget has an orange background):

[image].

When I change the `border-width` to 10, the border covers the contents:

[image]

Both images show the widget in its minimum height.

To me it looks as if the border were applied inwards. What shall I modify to point the border outwards, so for a larger `border-width` the text remains visible?

Comment: Prevent the widget from being shrunk by setting its minimum size to an appropriate value using [`QWidget::setMinimumSize`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setMinimumSize-1).

Comment: My custom widget already has a MinimumHeight and MinimumWidth.The pics(1 & 2) above are with the widget in its MinimumHeight.But for this height,when I set a border-width of 10,it is like pic2.Is there anyway by which I can make the border go outwards??

Comment: The border does go outwards. See here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqClz.png You have a problem with the size.

Comment: I tried setting the MinimumSize.But for that Minimum Size,when I set a bigger border-width,the same problem exists!!

Comment: What is the type of `customWidget`? What is the minimum size you set?

Comment: I have set Minimize size as (30,30).Its just a normal custom widget with mouseEvents!!

Comment: (30, 30) is too small for this border. See here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cjmO.png Set a reasonable size, e.g. (100, 50).

Comment: Alternatively you might implement `sizeHint` and `minimumSizeHint` of your widget in order to calculate the required size automatically. See how it is done in [QLabel](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qlabel.cpp.html#_ZNK6QLabel8sizeHintEv) for example.

Comment: Why should we implement them?I cant understand the given link!

Comment: Setting the minimum size is not flexible, meaning, that it does not account for changes in the widget's content. If the `sizeHint` is implemented though, the necessary space will be reported whenever needed.

Comment: I suggest you to show your custom widget class. Perhaps I would be able to propose an implementation of the size hint.

Comment: Hi scopchanov,I have attached my custom Widget implementation.Apologies for a late response..

Comment: and the constructor?

Comment: please have a look at the edit:I have updated the constructor

Comment: How does the code you have provided produce the result shown in the image?

Comment: Th orange is the Bg color set to the parent .Whereas my label is the childWidget to which I have already set text.Both of them are being passed as constructor arguments .

Comment: I am sorry, but I am still not able to reproduce the issue. For me the border is correct. See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBmNd.png). If you want to get help with your issue, you have to make it reproducible. For that purpose create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I will soon update the reproduceable code!!

Comment: In addition I have set the minimum width and height to (30,30) .Now ,the border will hide the label

Comment: don't set it and it should be fine.

Comment: But as per my requirement,I have this minimum size and for this size we need to set border also.

Comment: I hope you do realize that `30 - 2*10` (the minimum height - 2 times the width of the border) equals `10`. Your font is larger than 10px, so how do you imagine to fit it in the remaining space?

Comment: oh..now I understand the actual problem.I will accept it as an answer.Could you add this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Cause

The border does go outwards:

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/EqClz.png]

You have a problem with the size. `(30, 30)` is too small for this border. `30 - 2*10` (the minimum height - 2 times the width of the border) equals `10`. Your font is larger than 10px, so it does not fit in the remaining space.

## Solution

You might want to set a reasonable size, e.g. (100, 50). However, setting the minimum size is not flexible, meaning, that it does not account for changes in the widget's content. If the `sizeHint` and `minimumSizeHint` are implemented though, the necessary space will be reported whenever needed, as it is done in [`QLabel`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qlabel.cpp.html#_ZNK6QLabel8sizeHintEv) for example.

Since you already have a `QLabel` as a child widget, just avoid setting the `minimumSize` of your custom widget and the correct size will be calculated automatically.

Comment: I would like to have a custom implementation of sizehint like the one you have shared,but as Im new to qt,Im unable to understand it;Could you share some tutorials or book so that I can understand and implement on my own!!

Comment: @adi, [size hint is the preferred size of the widget, layouts will try to keep it as close to this as possible.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20328179/5366641). Basically you have to return a `QSize`, which you calculate based on the widget space requirements, e.g. border width, margins, padding and contents. If you post a new question with a particular example content, I will try to implement a `sizeHint` for you.